# My Flash project is too heavy to run smoothly

Tags: flash, animated-gif, flash-cs6

I've just imported a gif file into my Flash projetct, but you can see here. my project increase almost 2.5GB just when i have imported 60s gif in it.

[image: here is what i've just imported Gif file]
[image: my flash file]
Now it's really hard to modify frames...cuz this software run slowly (always loading) even thought other processes are still run smoothly, except Flash software.

Comment: Does the 60 gif files add up to around 2.5 gb? Why use gif animation (pixel data) inside a flash animation (shapes data)? If you need moving images use a video format not gif.. I mean add a video object and give it some video URL to decode (don't import every single frame of video, otherwise it'll be same problem as gif frames)

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try this option: **`Import to Libray`**?

If it's not useful, you should review your animation, such as checking if any actionscript is doing intensive code tasks.

[image]

Comment: thanks but how to check actionscript is doing intensive code tasks.